# NoReverseMatch as consequence of a form action

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, django-views, django-templates

This is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.rando, name="rando"),
    path("wiki", views.index, name="index"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.title, name="title"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>/edit", views.edit, name="edit"),
]
```

This is my views.py:

```
def edit(request, title):
    if request.method=="POST":
        content = request.POST.get("content")
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return redirect(f'/wiki/{title}')
    elif request.method=="GET":
        if title in util.list_entries():
            ge = util.get_entry(title)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
                "title": title,
                "ge": ge
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
```

This is what I want to render (edit.html):

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Edit {{title}}</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <textarea id="ctnt" name="content">{{ge}}</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>



{% endblock %}
```

When I want to send the form above with the current action it gives me: `NoReverseMatch at /wiki/CSS/edit` but when I remove action it doesn't display any error. Could you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: You are missing `title` within your form action: `{% url 'edit' title %}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reverse` method search for view that naming space. After that it tries to pass needed variables, but you didn't provide any with `{% url 'edit' %}`. It should be `{% url 'name' first_argument second_argument etc. %}`, so in your case: `{% url 'edit' title %}`.

But as I can see your view, it's actually pointless to do such action (cause you have redirect in `if request.method=="POST"` part), and by default try not to do that. It's good practice to have such backend behaviour directly in your `views.py` files.

Comment: Thank u so much :),  but why is better not to use redirect?

Comment: I meant that you should not use `action` in template. It's better to keep all behaviours in `views` - in this way you will always have full picture of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

For it to work django requires you pass a title to the url path. It should be something like this

```
<form action="{% url 'edit' wiki.title %}" method="post">
```

and not

```
 <form action="{% url 'edit' %}" method="post">
```